# PHP - cropping image with imagecopyresampled()?

Tags: php, image, resize, crop

I'd like to crop an image using imagecreatetruecolor and it always crops it leaving black spaces, or the zoom is too big. I want the image to be exactly 191px wide and 90px high, so I also need to resize the image, as well as crop, because the ratio has to be kept. Well, there are some samples of the project:

[image]

The resize script (simplified) goes like this:

```
$src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($photoTemp);    
list($width,$height)=getimagesize($photoTemp);
$dst_img=imagecreatetruecolor(191, 90);
imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $newImage['crop']['x'], $newImage['crop']['y'], $newImage['crop']['width'], $newImage['crop']['height'], $width, $height);
```

The $newImage['crop'] array includes:

```
['x'] => $_POST['inp-x']
['y'] => $_POST['inp-x']
['width'] => $_POST['inp-width']
['height'] => $_POST['inp-height']
```

But what I get is:

[image]

Anyone sees, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks, Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem myself, the code should be like this:

```
imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $newImage['crop']['x'], $newImage['crop']['y'], $newImage['newWidth'], 191, 90, $newImage['crop']['height']);
```

Answer (score 5):

you can do it too, I myself did it, and it works

(x1,y1)=> where crop starts

(x2,y2)=> where crop ends

```
$filename = $_GET['imageurl'];
$percent = 0.5;

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

$new_width  = $_GET['x2'] - $_GET['x1'];
$new_height = $_GET['y2'] - $_GET['y1'];

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0 , $_GET['x1'] , $_GET['y1'] , $new_width, $new_height, $new_width, $new_height);

// Outputs the image
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php

$dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($newImage['crop']['width'], $newImage['crop']['height']);

imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $newImage['crop']['x'], $newImage['crop']['y'], 0, 0, $width, $height);
```

Comment: Tryed id, what I get is just a black image. =/

Answer (score 0):

There's also the [imagecrop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php) function, which allows you to pass in an array with `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` values.