# Crop image without stretching it, inside PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, crop

I am making a upload form inside PHP. Though I want the form to upload a thumbnail that is exactly, lets say, 100px high and 100px width. The form has to rescale the tumbnail without stretching the image, but by removing a part from the image. I prefer to do this with 100% php and the most simple script. I already have made my upload form and I only want to know how to make this auto-crop system with my tumbnails.

I really hope you can help me out and I want to thank you in advance.

My script already uploads a image with a thumbnail:

```
if( $imgtype == 'image/jpeg' ){ $filetype= '.jpg'; }else{ $filetype= str_replace ( 'image/', '', $imgtype ); }

$path= 'images/' . md5( rand( 0, 1000 ) . rand( 0, 1000 ) . rand( 0, 1000 ) . rand( 0, 1000 ) ) . '.jpg';
$thumb_path= 'images/thumb_' . md5( rand( 0, 1000 ) . rand( 0, 1000 ) . rand( 0, 1000 ) . rand( 0, 1000 ) ) . '.jpg';
$imgsize2= getimagesize( $imgtemp );
$width= $imgsize2[0];
$height= $imgsize2[1];

$maxwidth= 1281;
$maxheight= 721;
$allowed= array( 'image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', );

if( in_array( $imgtype, $allowed ) ){

    if( $width < $maxwidth && $height < $maxheight ){

    if( $imgsize < 5242880 ){

        if( $width == $height ){ $case=1; }
        if( $width > $height ){ $case=2; }
        if( $width < $height ){ $case=3; }

        switch( $case ){

            case 1:

            $newwidth= 100;
            $newheight= 100;

            break;

            case 2:

            $newheight= 100;
            $ratio= $newheight / $height;
            $newwidth= round( $width * $ratio );

            break;

            case 3:

            $newwidth= 100;
            $ratio= $newwidth / $width;
            $newheight= $height * $ratio;

            break;

            }

            switch( $imgtype ){

                case 'image/jpeg';

                $img= imagecreatefromjpeg( $imgtemp );
                $thumb= imagecreatetruecolor( $newwidth, $newheight );
                imagecopyresized( $thumb, $img, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height );
                imagejpeg( $thumb, $thumb_path );  

                break;

                case 'image/png';

                $img= imagecreatefrompng( $imgtemp );
                $thumb= imagecreatetruecolor( $newwidth, $newheight );
                imagecopyresized( $thumb, $img, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height );
                imagepng( $thumb, $thumb_path ); 

                break;

                case 'image/gif';

                $img= imagecreatefromgif( $imgtemp );
                $thumb= imagecreatetruecolor( $newwidth, $newheight );
                imagecopyresized( $thumb, $img, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height );
                imagegif( $thumb, $thumb_path ); 

                break;

                } if(empty($errors))  {

        move_uploaded_file( $imgtemp, $path );
        $upimage = "Image is successfully uploaded.";
                }
        } else{
        $errors[9] = "The image you just uploaded does not meet the requirements. Your picture is too large. ";
        }

        } else{
        $errors[10] = "The image you just uploaded does not meet the requirements. It is a forbidden extension.";
        }

    } else{
        $errors[11] = "The image you just uploaded does not meet the requirements. It is a forbidden extension. Type: $imgtype,  $image, $imgsize, $imgtemp, $name";
        }
if(empty($errors))  {
move_uploaded_file( $imgtemp, $path );
}
     }
```

Comment: have you really not tried a google search? http://www.google.com/search?q=php+crop+image

Comment: I did but it's either too difficult or it's not exactly what I mean. But thanks for your help.

Comment: what part of it is difficult? this site is for asking questions about something you're stuck on, not asking for complete solutions to a problem you haven't even attempted to solve yet.

Comment: sgroves, what you say is not true. Why do you get the impression that I didn't do my research? The question is how I can crop an image without stretching it inside a PHP upload form. My script already makes a thumbnail but I want it to upload a thumbnail with an exact width and height

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255773/

Comment: Can you than point out to me where I can find the solution to my problem? Because I really can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to set the x and y coordinates to **crop** an image. Try something like this. You might have to play with the `top` and `left` numbers until you get it where you want. Take note of the `imagecopyresized` line. 
Also here is a similar post with an identical answer [PHP - cropping image with imagecopyresampled()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970466/php-cropping-image-with-imagecopyresampled?rq=1)
You need to set the x and y parameters as noted below. BTW the answer was really easy to find. SO even provides related questions on the right hand side of the page where I found that other example for you. Cheers.

```
          switch( $case ){

        case 1:
        $top = 50;
        $left = 50;   
        $newwidth= 100;
        $newheight= 100;

        break;

        case 2:

        $newheight= 100;
        $ratio= $newheight / $height;
        $newwidth= round( $width * $ratio );

        break;

        case 3:

        $newwidth= 100;
        $ratio= $newwidth / $width;
        $newheight= $height * $ratio;

        break;

        }

        switch( $imgtype ){

            case 'image/jpeg';

            $img= imagecreatefromjpeg( $imgtemp );
            $thumb= imagecreatetruecolor( $newwidth, $newheight );
            imagecopyresized( $thumb, $img, 0,0,$left,$top, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height );
            imagejpeg( $thumb, $thumb_path );  

            break;

            case 'image/png';

            $img= imagecreatefrompng( $imgtemp );
            $thumb= imagecreatetruecolor( $newwidth, $newheight );
            imagecopyresized( $thumb, $img, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height );
            imagepng( $thumb, $thumb_path ); 

            break;

            case 'image/gif';

            $img= imagecreatefromgif( $imgtemp );
            $thumb= imagecreatetruecolor( $newwidth, $newheight );
            imagecopyresized( $thumb, $img, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height );
            imagegif( $thumb, $thumb_path ); 

            break;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it really helped me. I am wondering why some can't understand my question. I really apreciate your understanding.

Comment: No problem just glad I could help. It WAS valid and you even provided working code that just needed a **small** tweak. Just because no one seemed to understand your question doesn't mean it's not a real question. I know it's irritating sometimes. Anyway, I've worked a lot with uploading images on my site so I knew what your were talking about. Good luck.