# Cropping images with Php

Tags: php, image, crop

I'm using Jquery plugin ImgAreaSelect with PHP 5.3.9 with GD 2.0.34.

Following some examples from the plugin, I added a form that gives X and Y values from where I start selecting the image till the end of the selection.

This is going OK, because I recieve the values correctly, but I cannot crop the image. Followed some examples/tutorials but always failed.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$x1 = $_POST['x1']; //this one gives me the point where start to crop
$x2 = $_POST['x2']; //the end of X axis
$y1 = $_POST['y1']; //same for Y1 and Y2
$y2 = $_POST['y2'];
$w = $x2 - $x1; //getting the width for the new image
$h = $y2 - $y1; //getting the height for the new image
$src_img = "path/image";
$format = end(explode(".", $src_img)); //taking the image format (jpg, png, gif)
$size = getimagesize($src_img);
switch($format) {
    case "jpg":
        $copy = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_img);
        $new = ImageCreateTrueColor($w, $h);
        imagecopyresampled($new, $copy, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $w, $h, $size[0], $size[1]);
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($new);
    break;
}
```

I would like to know if there's something wrong (most probably).

Thanks for all and taking your time to help.

Comment: spelling of switch ????

Comment: my bad, but no, is not that, i type it by hand and I made a mistake.

Comment: ok..so does it give some error ? or it just resizes the image ?

Comment: @Deepanshu I just commented the header line, and it resizes the image, as you say.

Comment: is $src_img = "path/image"; correct?

Comment: `$src_img = "path/image";` ... `$copy = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_src);`... src_img or img_src?

Comment: my bad again, yes, its src_img. and yes, the path it's correct.

Comment: someone told me to change the 0,0,$x1,$y1 to $x1,$y1,0,0, it cropped it, but the image went backwards, letting a blackbackground at the top and left. but the answer was deleted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970466/php-cropping-image-with-imagecopyresampled might help you

Comment: the only thing you need to check is the parameters value and order in imagecopyresampled()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imagecopyresampled($new, $copy, $x1, $y1, 0, 0, $w, $h, $size[0], $size[1]);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

> In other words, imagecopyresampled() will take a rectangular area from src_image **of width src_w and height src_h** at position (src_x,src_y) and place it in a rectangular area of dst_image of width dst_w and height dst_h at position (dst_x,dst_y).

in other words, you need to change it to:

```
imagecopyresampled($new, $copy,0 ,0 ,$x1, $y1, $w, $h, $w, $h);
```

Comment: thanks you too, the only thing is that $x and $y goes after the 0, 0 values, now is working perfectly. thanks!

Comment: @Ardilla: whoops, my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you can try this code also

```
<?php
  $x1 = $_POST['x1']; //this one gives me the point where start to crop
  $x2 = $_POST['x2']; //the end of X axis
  $y1 = $_POST['y1']; //same for Y1 and Y2
  $y2 = $_POST['y2'];
  $w  = ( $x2 - $x1 ); //getting the width for the new image
  $h  = ( $y2 - $y1 ); //getting the height for the new image

  $src  = "path_to_file";
  $info = getimagesize( $src );

  switch( $info[2] ) {
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
      $copy = imagecreatefromjpeg( $src );
      $new  = imagecreatetruecolor( $w, $h );
      imagecopyresampled( $new, $copy, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $info[0], $info[1], $w, $h );
      header( 'Content-type: image/jpeg' );
      imagejpeg( $new );
    break;
    default:
    break;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//resize and crop image by center
function resize_crop_image($max_width, $max_height, $source_file, $dst_dir, $quality = 80){
    $imgsize = getimagesize($source_file);
    $width = $imgsize[0];
    $height = $imgsize[1];
    $mime = $imgsize['mime'];

    switch($mime){
        case 'image/gif':
            $image_create = "imagecreatefromgif";
            $image = "imagegif";
            break;

        case 'image/png':
            $image_create = "imagecreatefrompng";
            $image = "imagepng";
            $quality = 7;
            break;

        case 'image/jpeg':
            $image_create = "imagecreatefromjpeg";
            $image = "imagejpeg";
            $quality = 80;
            break;

        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }

    $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($max_width, $max_height);
    $src_img = $image_create($source_file);

    $width_new = $height * $max_width / $max_height;
    $height_new = $width * $max_height / $max_width;
    //if the new width is greater than the actual width of the image, then the height is too large and the rest cut off, or vice versa
    if($width_new > $width){
        //cut point by height
        $h_point = (($height - $height_new) / 2);
        //copy image
        imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, $h_point, $max_width, $max_height, $width, $height_new);
    }else{
        //cut point by width
        $w_point = (($width - $width_new) / 2);
        imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $w_point, 0, $max_width, 
Resize and crop image from center with PHP


$max_height, $width_new, $height);
    }

    $image($dst_img, $dst_dir, $quality);

    if($dst_img)imagedestroy($dst_img);
    if($src_img)imagedestroy($src_img);
}
//usage example
resize_crop_image(100, 100, "test.jpg", "test.jpg");
```

Answer (score -1):

thanks to all, @Deepanshu gave me a link wich I saw a piece of code, but somehow strange:
`bool imagecopyresampled ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h )`

the last `$src_w` and `$src_h` I had to put the new width and the new height, instead the width and height of the original image.

so, the final code working properly is:

`imagecopyresampled($new, $copy, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $w, $h, $w, $h);`

Comment: There is no need to post thanks like this, in fact please don't unless you are providing an answer to your own question. This doesn't seem to be an answer, so it should be a comment. On SO we thank each other by voting up and accepting answers.